# Issue with VBA script in Word

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

I have a macro enabled form that someone will download from Sharepoint, fill out and then I want them to click on a button and it will save to a document folder on the SharePoint site.

I recorded a Macro that worked but there is a variable where I want the filename to be todays date. I modified the code and now it will not work. I get 1 of 3 errors.

1. I get a 4198 command failed error when I have https in front of the site address
2. The ChangeFileOpenDirectory command gives a 4172 path not found error
3. I remove https and ChangeFileOpenDirectory and get a 5152 file or folder not found error

The code I added is in bold.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' these next lines would be bold if you could make code bold
Dim filename1 As String
filename1 = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
' the lines above

  ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "https://SP ADDRESS/sites/SITE NAME/Shared%20Documents/FOLDER NAME/"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        "https://SP ADDRESS/sites/SITE NAME/Shared%20Documents/FOLDER NAME/" **& filename1 & ".docm"** _
        , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, LockComments:=False, _
        Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
        SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
        False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The code (without the ChangeFileOpenDirectory call, which you shouldn't need) worked OK here. Does FOLDER NAME actually have spaces in it or other characters that need to be escaped using % notation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The folder name does not have spaces or other characters in it, it is all letters in 1 string

Comment: 2 days I have been working on it - tried without the ChangeFile line and it works.... thank you for replying mate.

Comment: I think you just added a comment then deleted it (about saving as a different format). I guess you solved that. But I just started to look at it, and I realised that although the code successfully saved a .docm to my SP folder, I couldn't re-open it. Word creates a document WIndow with nothing in it. Perhaps a macro setting problem here, but I thought I'd mention it in case you hade a similar problem.

Comment: @slightlysnarky Indeed, I was asking about a file type change but docm is it as it is a macro. I had the same issue hence trying to save as XML or docx. It was a trusted location issue (and enabling macros) in trust center that resolved it. Thanks

Comment: Good. If you can write up an Answer that would be good. I'd do it myself if I was completely sure about what you actually had to do to solve the problem.